# Slight network lag on Small Business Server 2008 R2

Tags: network-share, windows-sbs-2008, dell-poweredge

I recently upgraded a network from a SBS 2003 server to a SBS 2008 R2 Server. Both I and users have noticed a slight delay in network applications and browsing network drives on the new server. It is minor, maybe a second or two at most. However I am wondering if anyone knows of anyway to optimize the networking to service requests sooner to the workstations.

The network is running a 1 gig network with some 100 meg devices (mainly network printers). All workstations are XP SP3
Network software runs out of a shared folder mapped as a network drive, no sql databases.
Server is a Dell Poweredge T610 with plenty of ram, cpu power, and storage.

Answer (score 0):

During the migration did you migrate shares from the old server to the new one, or does the new server have the old server's name and share configuration?

Quite often there are references left behind that refer back to the old server name (in office file metadata, and offline files to name a couple). If that network name is not available, lookups can stall for a couple of seconds. You can test this quite quickly by adding a hosts file entry for the old server's name, pointing to the new server's IP address. If this resolves the issue, you know where the problem lies and can start to dig out those references.

Comment: It wasn't a proper migration. It was a fresh install with the network applications coppied over and new shares setup. All the computers were re-joined to the new domain. Users were given new profiles with documents copied back via external hdd. It allowed for some much needed clean up.

The new server and domain are both new names, as well as a new server ip.

Would the host file entries still relate for this setup? I'll give it a shot either way on one of the workstations.

Thanks so far.